# What does this sentence mean? "...without a similar condition including this condition being imposed on the subsequent purchaser."

Tags: meaning, sentence

I cannot fully comprehend a part of the following sentence:

> Except in the United States of America, this book is sold subject to the condition that it shall not, by way of trade or otherwise, be lent, re-sold, hired out, or otherwise circulated without the publisher's prior consent in any form of binding or cover other than that in which it is published and **without a similar condition including this condition being imposed on the subsequent purchaser.**

I understand the most of it but the bold part is a bit confusing. What does it mean exactly? Does it mean that the condition cannot be altered?

Comment: It's confusing because of the double negative. The first condition is a "shall not", and then that contains "without a similar condition"

Comment: Adding a protective plastic or leather cover needs thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

It means that if you lend, re-sell, hire out, or otherwise circulate the book outside the US, (which you should only do in the original binding or cover, *or* with the publisher's prior permission), then you have to make the person/entity receiving the book agree to these same terms.

So basically in most cases the original binding or cover is going to have to stay on the book.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it easily now. What confused me was that the saying "a similar condition including this condition". I suppose it is a generalisation of the exact condition and the condition the publisher agreed upon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It may help you to know that this kind of repetitious BS language is not good English, but legal language with a fixed meaning. Of course this condition of binding is included in similar conditions, my God!